# Is Linux behavior in VirtualBox a more or less reliable indicator of physical installation behavior?

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm a Linux newb, I started out with a dual-boot install of Ubuntu 18.04 on an old Macbook that natively runs OS X El Capitan. I've found Ubuntu rather frustrating, first it was lots of hang issues, now it's boot issues that I may or may not continue to try to fix... anyway, I'm now trying Mint on a VirtualBox installation. I haven't gotten too deep into it yet because I've been kind of busy the last few days, but so far it seems to be much more stable and less buggy than my Ubuntu dual-boot install.

So my question is, if a Linux distro runs well on a virtual machine (VirtualBox, in this case), does that behavior typically carry over to if and when it's actually installed on the machine? I'm sure that may depend a lot on distro, machine specs, possibly other factors as well, but I'm interested in hearing from people's experiences as much as (if not more than) raw technical knowledge. Especially pertaining to Ubuntu and Mint.

I'll post some of my machines specs here below, in case that can help anyone get some insight. Thank you all for reading, and let me know if there's any further info I can give to help answer the question.

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M GPU

Broadcom Bluetooth Chipset

RAM: 6 GB DDR2 800 MHz SDRAM

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo (2.13 GHz), 2 cores, L2: 3MB

Hard drive: Samsung 1 TB (~493 GB for Ubuntu, ~6 GB swap, rest Mac OS). Old school HD, not solid state.

My Mac OS version is El Capitan, 10.11.6

Comment: VMs run on virtual hardware and are in no way indicative of performance on your real hardware. The easiest way to tell is to just boot to a live CD/DVD/USB and see if things work.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, if a Linux distro runs well on a virtual machine (VirtualBox, in this case), does that behavior typically carry over to if and when it's actually installed on the machine?

VirtualBox (and other hypervisors like VMWare WorkStation, kvm, qemu) emulates a standard set of hardware which has almost nothing to do with your real hardware. The only piece of HW which gets passed to a virtual OS more or less unchanged is your CPU.

Comment: And even the CPU is somewhat "simplified" by the fact that e.g. its power management features are normally handled by the actual host OS/hypervisor only.

Comment: Thank you to all who have answered!